# WPF FolderBrowserDialog using Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have to get FolderBrowserDialog once I click the browse button,but I should achieve that by using MVVM.

Explanation:

1. Once I get the FolderBrowserDialog Box, I should able to select the folder in which I'm wishing to save my files.
2. Then after selecting the folder,it should show me the selected folderpath along with the foldername in the Textbox beside my browse button.

   How can I achieve this....

Comment: It is not a responsibility of vm to show filedialog. You should do this in code behind and then use vm from DataContext property to call a method in vm

Comment: Write method in your code behind with OpenFileDialog and in the same method cast `(YourVM)DataContext` and call method in VM from it. That's it.

Comment: No I'm asking FolderBrowserDialog not OpenFileDialog...Both are different right? @FCin

Comment: You might want to check [my article and code on MVVM Dialog Boxes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/%2FArticles%2F820324%2FImplementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM). Going from memory, I don't think I specifically added the folder dialog chooser, but if not it'd only take a few lines to add if you base it off the one for OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Best solution on SO so far. I like the idea to encapsulate the dialog logic into a behavior. This makes the dialog handling reusable and keeps it in the domain of the view. You should definitely dedicate an answer to this. Otherwise there are too much bad recommendations like handling the dialog controls in the view model around.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Attached behaviors are an elegant way to make code-behind logic reusable and extensible.

Comment: @Bionic thanks! Links aren't really considered answers on SO though, and my one contains a lot of info that wouldn't fit into the SO question/answer format. Appreciate the comment though.

Comment: @MarkFeldman It's really a pity that people searching SO before searching the web in order to find such articles. Although SO also helped me when beginning, I think if I had a company, I would block the URL. In production I have witnessed so much copy&paste of bad code that caused a lot of time consuming trouble. All because of the lack of some basic understanding. I've worked with developers that can't understand their own code and thus were not able to fix it. As an excuse they said it was copied from SO. I will recommend your article any time this topic comes up again. And it will for sure.

Comment: @Bionic it's a problem, to be sure. I've run a software company in the past and my two rules for cut-n-paste (be it SO or anywhere else) were 1) give every line at least a rough look-over to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing, and 2) add the URL you got it from to the top so that everyone at least knows where it came from. If you're also doing code-vetting then that should catch most problems, without the time/money hit of forcing complete re-writes for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about binding.

In this simple example i added a button that is bind to a Command - that replaces the code behind event.I used also in a Nuget that extant the ICommand and implement it ( along with a lot of other functionality ) - The name of the Nuget is Prism6.MEF.

Here is the example :

Xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindableTextProperty}" />
        <Button Content ="Do Action" Command="{Binding DoAction}" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind :

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
    }
}
```

View Model :

```
   class MainWindowVM : BindableBase
{
    private string m_bindableTextProperty;


    public MainWindowVM() 
    {
        DoAction = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDoAction,CanExecuteDoAction); 
    }


    public string BindableTextProperty
    {
        get { return m_bindableTextProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref m_bindableTextProperty , value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand DoAction
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteDoAction()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteDoAction() 
    { 
      // Do something
      // You could enter the Folder selection code here 
        BindableTextProperty = "Done"; 
    }
}
```

As i explained at the begin with to understand why it works you have to understand the Binding in WPF and especially the INotifyPropertyChange - for the Data on the TextBlock

Hope it helped :)